# How can I get doxygen to continue a list with bullets in between?

Tags: doxygen

i want to get my doxygen code to keep the list formats continuing with bullets in between.

```
void function(void)
{
   int a = 3;
   
   //! -#if a is 3, do the following:
   if(a == 3)
   {
        //! - Do magic math with a; 
        a = a * 23;
   }

   //! -#if b is 3, do the following:
   if(b == 3)
   {
        //! - Do magic math with b; 
        b = b * 23;
   }
}
```

I want the output to be :

```
1) if a is 3, do the following:
    - Do magic math with a
2) if b is 3, do the following:
    - Do magic math with b
```

but doxygen is generating it as :

```
1) if a is 3, do the following:
    - Do magic math with a
1) if b is 3, do the following:
    - Do magic math with b
```

Any thoughts on how to get the list to continue?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? I don't see any difference between your supplied required and actual output.

Comment: version is 1.8.11. fixed the output.

Comment: The doxygen 1.8.11 version is old (December 30, 2015) the current version is 1.9.2, so I would certainly advise to update (although this will have no effect on your (problem).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have an auto-numbered (markdown) list (see e.g. the documentation ("Markdown support")). Doxygen requires that a list starts and ends in one comment block and in your case the list is distributed over 2 comment blocks, hence the second lists starts at 1 again.

Doxygen has 2 other possibilities for lists

- `\li`, this will not give good results ether
- `<LI>` gives more the possibility to work with blocks (though the solution is very situation specific). When we convert the code to:

  ```
  /// fie_html
  void fie_html(void)
  {
     int a = 3;

     //! <ol>
     //! <li> if a is 3, do the following:
     if(a == 3)
     {
          //! - Do magic math with a;
          a = a * 23;
     }

     //! <li> if b is 3, do the following:
     if(b == 3)
     {
          //! - Do magic math with b;
          b = b * 23;
     }
     //! </ol>
  }
  ```

  we will get as a result:

  [image]

  and as as far as I can judge this is the result you would like to obtain.
- `<LI value='...'>` so we don't need to work with large blocks:

  ```
  /// fie_html_value
  void fie_html_value(void)
  {
     int a = 3;

     //! <ol>
     //! <li value='1'> if a is 3, do the following:
     if(a == 3)
     {
          //! - Do magic math with a;
          a = a * 23;
     }
     //! </ol>

     //! <ol>
     //! <li value='3'> if b is 3, do the following:
     if(b == 3)
     {
          //! - Do magic math with b;
          b = b * 23;
     }
     //! </ol>
  }
  ```

  this results in:

  [image]

  I explicitly used `3` here to show the effect, so I think also the effect you want.

  (NOTE: this only works, currently, in HTML and not in e.g. LaTeX / pdf, RTF, docbook).